# Where do I buy ground coffee around Kata beach, Thailand?

Tags: food-and-drink, thailand, shopping

Could you please tell me where can I purchase ground coffee around [Kata beach](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Kata+Beach), Thailand?

I've tried various small shops like 7-Eleven and Tesco Express, but they only sell instant coffee.

Comment: Close voters: this is not a *price-shopping* question, since they're not asking about the "best" or "cheapest" coffee.

Comment: @jpatokal OK, sure, but it's very location-specific and the information will quickly go out of date. So, while it's not a _price_ shopping question, it is a shopping question that should be closed for all the same reasons.

Comment: @DavidRicherby If you can coherently explain why this is off-topic while the following question is not, please do so on Meta: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/115675/jain-food-options-in-nyc-wall-street

Comment: @jpatokal Claiming that one question is off-topic does not oblige me to make determinations on any and all other similar questions. I have explained why I believe *this* question is off-topic and that is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Starbucks:

Kata Center, 4 Taina Road Tambon Karon, Amphoe Mueang Chang Wat Phuket 83100, Thailand
+66 76 285 282 https://g.co/kgs/nG2McT

Comment: I've bought a package of very nice ground coffee from Starbucks, thanks! Didn't know they sell the raw coffee.