# Jain food options in NYC (Wall Street)

Tags: food-and-drink, new-york-city

I will be travelling to NYC in June and will be staying in the Wall Street area. I follow a strict Jain diet (i.e. strict vegetarian with no onion, garlic, potato, or eggs in any food preparation) and would like to follow it while in NY.

I have been enquiring with the hotel I'm going to stay in and the nearby restaurants but the response has not been too enthusiastic. I tried searching on Yelp and various food delivery sites but the results are not that many (or they try to push regular vegetarian food as Jain food). I wanted to know what options are available to me (preferably closer to Wall Street).

Additionally, if there are some places that you would recommend (for jain food, obviously), in and around New York, do let me know (Something for the weekends :))

Comment: Great question.  (One solution is to go to a certain different city and eat at Swati Snacks  :)  )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Ahimsa](http://www.ahimsa.nyc) offers a substantial Jain menu.  They have two locations, one in Greenwich Village and the other in the East Village.  Both are about 3–4 km away from Wall Street, but you might be able to find a delivery service who are willing to deliver that distance.